# preg_replace для множественной замены в строке

Tags: php

Есть регулярка

https://regex101.com/r/DOYzGI/1/

Нужно emi обрамить тегом `<i>`, а mise тегом `<u>`

Вариант 1: Работает но не так как надо
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f15f2705fe55b9fe643314124da18042079a2b7
Работает с ошибкой. В замене `"SS$1YY"` приклеивается к переменной

Вариант 2: Ошибка
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0252eb0d4eae114b7e454e99b3e31e76a1502b29

Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in [...][...] on line 2

Я поменял `"SS$1YY"` на `"SS{$1}YY"` но так вроде всегда можно было, почему сейчас не работает?

Comment: Может лучше использовать две регулярки?

Comment: @Anamnian лучше. Но допустим это тестовое задание и надо сделать в одну строку.

Comment: Если верить Макконнеллу, Главный Технический Императив разработки есть управление сложностью. Я бы не стал писать такой сложный код, даже если это тестовое задание.

Comment: две разные замены одной регуляркой сделать в принципе нельзя, если не использовать двух регулярок или функции обработчика замены, которая дополнительно проверит по какой из ветвей регулярки найдено совпадение

Comment: @fosh4455 покажите входную и выходную строку. так будет проще понимать

Comment: @Manitikyl входная строка `hemidemisemiquaver`

Comment: @fosh4455 а чем вам не угодил `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверяйте подстроку `emi` таким образом, что бы ни слева ни справа от неё не было символа **s**. Иначе говоря, нужно исключить из поиска в подстроке `emi` те позиции, которые входят в подстроку `mise`:

```
$string = 'hemidemisemiquaver';

$pattern = '~(?<!s)(emi)(?!s)|(mise)~';
$replace = '<i>$1</i><u>$2</u>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Результат:

```
h<i>emi</i><u></u>de<i></i><u>mise</u>miquaver
```

Но *preg_replace()* для этой задачи не подходит, т.к. в случае отсутствия совпадения во второй подмаске `$2` в результирующую подстроку всё равно будет добавлена пара пустых тегов `<u></u>` *(они ведь жёстко прописаны в строке замены)*.

Альтернативным вариантом будет *preg_replace_callback()* -- в теле callback-функции можно добавить условие с проверкой на соответствие для второй подмаски:

```
$string = 'hemidemisemiquaver';

$pattern = '~(?<!s)(emi)(?!s)|(mise)~';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($mch) {
    return empty($mch[2]) ? "<i>$mch[1]</i>" : "<u>$mch[2]</u>";
}, $string);
```

Результат:

```
h<i>emi</i>de<u>mise</u>miquaver
```